# newInstance(map) for Grails domain classes?

Tags: grails, groovy

There is a domain class with field `id` being injected by Grails. Instantiating such a class with a map results in `id == null`:

```
def obj = DomainClass.class.newInstance(id:100, name:'Joe')
assert obj.id != null // it fails
```

What is the best practice to assign all the hidden properties in Grails?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize how GORM generates identifiers for the database using the DSL. By default GORM relies on the native database mechanism for generating ids. Check the documentation to [customizes the way the identifier for a domain class is generated](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned'
}
```

There is a bug over id initialization on constructor when generator is assigned, take a look to this blog post with a temporary workaround for this bug:
[Assigning ID for domain objects in Grails via constructor](http://www.redcube.de/assigning-id-domain-objects-grails-via-constructor/).

Comment: This is _not_ a bug, it is intentional. It is there to protect a hacker from sending in a different value for the id to an update method. Likewise `version`, `class`, and `metaclass` are excluded by default to reduce the likelihood of intentionally or mistakenly changing those with code like `thing.properties = params`. You can still manually assign the id if it makes sense for your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to say that there are a bug report in JIRA.